# Helidon Multipart - Unable to read multipart after converting Multi<ReadableBodyPart> as Single<List<ReadableBodyPart>>

Tags: java, multipartform-data, helidon

I'm currently using Helidon SE 2.5.0,as ReadableMultiPart is marked for deprication... I'm trying to use below code to retrieve list of bodyparts from server request but its not working....

```
serverRequest.content().asStream(ReadableBodyPart.class)
                        .collectList()
                        .forSingle(readableBodyParts -> readableBodyParts.
                                forEach(bodyPart -> {
                                    log.atInfo().log("I'm working...");
                                    bodyPart.drain();
                                }));
```

but direct forEach is working after reading as stream

```
      serverRequest.content().asStream(ReadableBodyPart.class)
                        .forEach(readableBodyPart ->{
                                    log.atInfo().log("I'm working...");
readableBodyPart.drain(); 
});
```

Please suggest the solution to make 1st code working.